# How to print brandnames when click its categoryname in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel-5

working with laravel 5.6 and mysql. I have following table name as `vehicles`

```
id  name  categoryname  brandname    model
1   juy   car           toyota       121
2   gty   van           nissan       caravan
3   bgh   car           bmw          520d
4   hyu   van           ford         max
5   nhj   car           toyota       121
```

i am using following controller function to display categorynames with links

```
public function showcategoryname()
    {
      $names = Vehicle::groupBy('categoryname')->select('id', 'categoryname', \DB::raw('COUNT(*) as cnt'))->get();  

      return view('welcome')->withNames($names);
    }
```

and in blade file,

```
@foreach($names as $name)
                    <tr>
                    <th><a href="{{$name->categoryname}}"></a></th>
                    <td><span class="label label-info">{{$name->cnt}}</span></td>

        </tr>
                    @endforeach
```

this is printing my categoryname with link as following
`car`
`van`

now I need when I clicked above categoryname then, displaying its related brand names? as an example when I click `car` categoryname Then page should displaying its brandnames like `toyota` `bmw` how can I do this in controller?

Comment: No any answers here?

Comment: No correction needed in your code.

Comment: @Bugfixer what did you mean?

Comment: He means that first you must try it by yourself and if you have any problems/bugs then you can ask for help on SO.

Comment: yes I have trying so many ways but not success

Comment: You should take a look at "database normalization", your `categories` and `brands` should have each have a seperate table and model and be "linked" via their `id`, rather than their names. Do you have model relations set up in your app? Do you have the route in place to show a single category?

Comment: all I have but no other table with brand names

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are new to Laravel, I would recommend going through the documentation or a good tutorial first. If you have an issue then first look for a solution in the documentation because you are new to Laravel and it will help you a lot. Google is always your friend. If you can not find a solution for your problem then post the question.

You should define a route in your routes/web.php file

```
Route::get('brands-by-category/{categortName}', 'YourController@brandsByCategory')->name('brands.by.category');
```

then you should write a method in YourController.

```
public class YourController
{
    ..........
    public function brandsByCategory($categoryName)
    {
     //your code here to get brands by category
    }
    ..........
}
```

then update your frontend code like this

```
@foreach($names as $name)
    <tr>
        <th><a href="{{route('brands.by.category', $name->categoryname)}}">{{$name->categoryname}}</a></th>
        <td><span class="label label-info">{{$name->cnt}}</span></td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

When you are going to click the category name in this page its going to redirect you to another page where you should display brands of that particular category.